# can I connect to hdfs without hadoop installation?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I've read the docs and tutorials and I can see that all nodes that are either namenode/datanode would need to install hadoop.

But what about the client that actually requests a file read/write operation on hdfs?

Does the client require hadoop installation too? Or can it just do hdfs i/o only by somehow communication with the namenode url?

For example in python, I've seen sample codes that import pyarrow and read data from hdfs by giving the namenode url as a parameter. In such cases, should hadoop installation be required?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Hadoop client libraries to be able to make RPC requests to the Hadoop services such as HDFS or YARN.

PyArrow, Spark, Flink, etc. are clients, and do not require a local Hadoop installation to run/write code.